# makefile Recipe for target failed in Dev C++

Tags: dev-c++

I am using Dev C++ v5.5.3
I have just written the code for the program and the makefile was generated by Dev C++.
I don't know anything about Makefiles. Here is the makefile generated by Dev C++.
I keep getting the error "recipe for target 'Dialogs_Private.res' failed".

Please help

```
# Project: Dialogs
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.5.3

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
RES      = Dialogs_private.res
OBJ      = Main.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = Main.o $(RES)
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib" -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include"
BIN      = Dialogs.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

Main.o: Main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c Main.cpp -o Main.o $(CXXFLAGS)

Dialogs_private.res: Dialogs_private.rc dialogResource.rc 
    $(WINDRES) -i Dialogs_private.rc --input-format=rc -o Dialogs_private.res -O coff
```

Comment: as pointed out in this identical question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084708/recipe-for-target-project1-exe-failed there is surely more error info than that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084708/recipe-for-target-project1-exe-failed)

Answer (score 0):

From your generated makefile we can find you are using your own resource script.

```
Dialogs_private.res: Dialogs_private.rc dialogResource.rc
```

DevC++ will generate a resource script(*ProjectName_private.rc*, in your case, is *Dialogs_private.rc*) and make a resource file(*ProjectName_private.res*) via that script. in your case, this generated *Dialogs_private.rc* file may like this:

```
/* THIS FILE WILL BE OVERWRITTEN BY DEV-C++ */
/* DO NOT EDIT! */

#include "dialogResource.rc"
```

As you can see, it just included your *dialogResource.rc*. DevC++ will try to compile it. if your resource script have some error, then it can not be compiled. Then you will see an error that tell you `recipe for target 'Dialogs_Private.res' failed` .

You should check your own resource script and have a look if there is any error in your script file. For example, are you missing some resource you are going to compile but you forget to place the resource file to the correct path? After all your own resource script compiled successfully, this error will be fixed.