# recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I try to compile a simple c file in `Dev-C++` and it shows an error on line 25
`C:\Users\varun\Desktop\cprog\Makefile.win  recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed.`

**Makefile.win**

```
# Project: Project1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.6.2

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = main.o Untitled2.o
LINKOBJ  = main.o Untitled2.o
LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++"
BIN      = Project1.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm.exe -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    **$(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)**

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c main.c -o main.o $(CFLAGS)

Untitled2.o: Untitled2.c
    $(CC) -c Untitled2.c -o Untitled2.o $(CFLAGS)
```

Errors

```
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\cprog\Untitled2.o    Untitled2.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\cprog\main.o main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\cprog\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
25      C:\Users\varun\Desktop\cprog\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed
```

Comment: It surely also says _why_ it failed. The makefile is generated and most probably correct. You have to show us the exact, complete output of the build command. Without that we can't help you.

Comment: Since it's the link command that failed, we are most probably looking for a linker error.

Comment: i have edited the question and add the output of the build command please take look

Comment: It says you have defined multiple main methods. Make sure you have not done this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important bit of the output is:

```
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\cprog\Untitled2.o    Untitled2.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
```

It tells you, that you have two definitions of function `main`. You need exactly one such definition in an executable. The next line of the error tells you, where that definition is:

```
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\cprog\main.o main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

So you have function `main` defined in `Untitled2.c` and you have another function `main` defined in `main.c`. Delete one of them. From the names perhaps the `main.c` is unnecessary altogether, but I can't tell without seeing the files.